# Find Dirichlet series of $2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, dirichlet-series

How can I find the Dirichlet series of $2^n$?

The Dirichlet series of a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is defined as $f(s) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$.

If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), then we have the following formula for Dirichlet series: $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \Pi_{p \text{ is prime }} g_p(p^{-s})$, where $g_p(x) := \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{p^n}x^n$ is the ordinary generating function of $\{a_{p^n}\}_{n = 0}^\infty$.

However, I can not use this formula, because $2^n$ is not multiplicative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^s} = \infty$

Thus the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^s}$ diverges $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$, according to [Cauchy convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test).

Comment: how can i use Cauchy convergence test to find the Dirichlet series of 2^n?

Comment: @Almaa, you can not find it because it diverges. The Dirichlet generating function of $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is defined as $f(s) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ for such $s$, for which the limit exists. And Cauchy convergence test shows, that this limit does not exist for any $s$.

Comment: how can i apply the Cauchy test here , i have $s\in{C}$ ?

Comment: @Almaa, suppose $b_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^n}{n^s}$ for some $s$. We know, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - b{n - 1}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^s} = \infty$ from that we can conclude, that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n > N$ we have $|b_{n+1}-b_n| > 1$. And Cauchy convergence criterion states, that any sequence $\{c_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ converges iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n_1, n_2 > N$ we have $|a_{n_1} - a_{n_2}|<\epsilon$. And now you see, that for $\{b_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ this is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Yanir Weg you mean $b_{n-1}$ right? Not $b_n$ -1 and $a_n$ 
not $c_n$ .thanks!

Comment: @Almaa, yes, you understood everything correctly.